# Which gene regulatory network is the largest in human?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, gene, network, biological-networks

What is the maximum number of nodes involved in any gene regulatory network and which network is it, provided its from human?

Comment: Your questions come across rather strangely. You don't explain why you would want to know something like this. I gather from your bio that it is related to your PhD project, so I imagine you have a reason. However I would suggest you are more likely to get a response on SE Bioinformatics. There are more people there who know what a node is.

Comment: It is not quite my field and I don't know how to answer this question but it strikes me as it is likely that the definition about what type of interactions you would consider to deserve being represented by an edge between the two genes (genes are nodes in this network) would matter a lot.

Comment: @David i did not know there is SE Bioinformatics,... thanks!